# Using different "et al." wordings when citing in text and in parentheses

Tags: citing, natbib, apacite

I'm writing my master's thesis and have a little issue with the citations. I'm using:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa, sectionbib, tocbib]{apacite}
```

for citations.

Currently, my shortened in-text and in-parentheses citations look like this:

> Smith et al. (1999)
>
> (Smith et al., 1999)

They need to look like this:

> Smith et alii (1999)
>
> (Smith et al., 1999)

So, if the short citation appears in text, the whole word should be written ("et alii"), and if it's in parentheses, the shortened version ("et al."). I've checked the `apacite` manual and have only found the `\BOthers` macro, which is used both for in-text and in-parentheses citations.

Is there a way to elegantly do this? E.g. define a new citation style, or modify the existing one?

Version info:

```
TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux
```

Comment: Is switching to biblatex an option for you?

Comment: If it's not a hassle, yes. The thesis is already written and I have to hand it in in 2 days, but got the feedback just earlier today. So if it doesn't require too much effort to switch (e.g. if it can be done with a simple sed/awk script or something), I'd be willing to give it a try.

Comment: Do you use the `apacite` bibliography style (along with the `apacite` LaTeX package), or do you use another bibliography style? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, the bibliography style is also `apacite`.

Comment: @Potato if you are this close to a deadline, don't try to change to biblatex.

Comment: Okay. Still, thanks for trying. The last resort is to create a `\newcommand` that uses `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`, and duplicate the problematic `.bib` entries, but only with the first author, and reference them. But I'd rather avoid this if possible.